# SQL server out of hour calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, datetime

### Out of hour calculation

An out of hour calendar defined as below,Here WeekNumber starts from 1 = Monday to 5 = Friday

```
CalendarId WeekNumber   StartTime           EndTime         
600         1           1900-01-01 00:00    1900-01-01 08:00    
600         1           1900-01-01 18:00    1900-01-01 23:59    
600         2           1900-01-01 00:00    1900-01-01 08:00    
600         2           1900-01-01 18:00    1900-01-01 23:59    
600         3           1900-01-01 00:00    1900-01-01 08:00    
600         3           1900-01-01 18:00    1900-01-01 23:59    
600         4           1900-01-01 00:00    1900-01-01 08:00    
600         4           1900-01-01 18:00    1900-01-01 23:59    
600         5           1900-01-01 00:00    1900-01-01 08:00    
600         5           1900-01-01 18:00    1900-01-01 23:59
```

I would like to apply this calendar to another table called events to find records falls in these day and times ?

### Edit

The Structure of event table as follows

```
EventID StartDateTime       TotalTimeInSec  WeekNumber  
1       2009-07-05 07:44     100                1 
2       2009-07-05 08:40     200                1
3       2009-07-05 09:35     150                1
4       2009-07-05 10:37     200                1
5       2009-07-05 19:37     200                1
6       2009-07-05 20:37     200                1
```

The required **output** will be after appyling the calendar

```
EventID StartDateTime       TotalTimeInSec  WeekNumber  
1       2009-07-05 07:44     100                1 
5       2009-07-05 19:37     200                1
6       2009-07-05 20:37     200                1
```

Comment: @Anoop Can you post the structure of events, in order to comparsion between two tables you need one common column between those tables.

Comment: @Viswanathan Iyer The structure is posted.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Select a.WeekNumber,a.startDateTime,b.starttime,b.EndTime
 from tblEvents a,(Select WeekNumber,Starttime,EndTime  from tblMain) b
 where a.startDateTime between b.starttime and b.EndTime
 and a.WeekNumber = b.WeekNumber
```

Comment: The calendar table has the week number and it should be compare with the events table. i.e. For Monday the event occured time falls between the monday timings in the calendar (WeekNumber = 1)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select E.*
From tblEvent E
Full outer Join tblMain M on E.WeekNumber = M.WeekNumber
Where E.StartDateTime Between M.StartTime and M.EndTime
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe a full outer join is what you're asking for. And the other answer didn't seem to handle your method of storing time ranges as datetime values. The only tricky part seems to be handling that date math. You can find different ways to do that check, but I think this is one solution.

```
SELECT e.*
FROM
    Events as e INNER JOIN Calendar as c
        ON c.WeekNumber = e.WeekNumber
WHERE
    /* CAST(CAST(e.StartDateTime AS TIME) AS DATETIME) -- later versions */
    e.StartDateTime - DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, e.StartDateTime), 0)        
        BETWEEN c.StartTime and e.EndTime
```